# Set application configuration based on selected Maven profile

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven project that I need to have its app config file content based on the selected maven profile.

The current config file is located:

`src/main/java/public/config.json`

It's a JSON config file:

```json
{
  "serverUrl" : "http://localhost:8080/api"
}
```

I want to have a "development" and "production" maven profile that sets the value of the `serverUrl` depending on the selected profile.

So if it's "production" the content of the JSON file would be:

```json
{
  "serverUrl" : "https://the-prod-server-url.com/api"
}
```

Comment: It is generally not a good idea to put stage specific configuration into a JAR or WAR. Instead, read the properties from an external source.

Comment: @JFabianMeier yes that is correct, but this app is a GWT app and it is just a pure Javascript application (GWT is a Java to Javascript compiler) so the only way to read it (the config) is from a static file also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use filtering in pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
   <profile>
       <id>development</id>
      <properties>
         <serverUrl>http://localhost:8080/api</serverUrl>
      </properties>
   </profile>
   
   <profile>
       <id>production</id>
      <properties>
         <serverUrl>https://the-prod-server-url.com/api</serverUrl>
      </properties>
   </profile>
</profiles>
```

```
<build>
   <resources>
       <resource>
           <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
           <filtering>true</filtering>
       </resource>
   </resources>
</build>
```

and then put `config.json` in `src/main/resources`:

```
{
  "serverUrl" : "${serverUrl}"
}
```

Comment: How about another location? Like `src/main/java/com/mycompany/public/config.json`?

Comment: I don't think you can use filtering for stuff under ```src/main/java```. If it is under ```src/main/resources``` you can read is at a classpath resource. Can that work for you?

Comment: If maven can copy the config file generated in the `src/main/resources` to `src/main/java/com/mycompany/public/config.json`

Comment: I havn't tried that solution. I think the textbook solution is to keep javastuff in ```src/main/java``` and config and other resources in ```src/main/resources```.

Comment: @Fireburn If you try my suggestion and that solves your issue, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.